# fetch api always getting fields are blank

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to login using PHP in react native so I am using fetch api but when I try to login it's always saying fields are blank whereas it's not. Can somebody help me with this?

Code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      Username: '',
      Password: '',
    }
  }
  login = () => {
    const {
      Username,
      Password
    } = this.state;
    var payload = {
      username: Username,
      password: Password
    };
    this.state[payload];
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append("json", JSON.stringify(payload));
    fetch("http://example.com/api.php", {
        method: 'POST',
        header: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-type': 'application/json'

        },
        body: data
      })
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
}
```

Text input:

```
<TextInput
style={styles.input}
placeholder={'Username'}
placeholderTextColor={'#fff'}
underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
onChangeText={Username => this.setState({ Username })}
/>

<TextInput
style={styles.input}
placeholder={'Password'}
secureTextEntry={this.state.showPass}
placeholderTextColor={'#fff'}
underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
onChangeText={Password => this.setState({ Password })}
/>
```

Comment: Add Value attr to your TextInput!

Comment: @DevAS something like this `value={this.state.Username}` ?

Comment: Yup, and check it again, then tell me what's you faced

Comment: @DevAS Same message fields are blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the **name** and **password** `status value`  are not empty, try this.

```js
let data = new FormData();
    data.append("username", this.state.Username);
data.append("password", this.state.Password);
fetch("http://example.com/api.php",{
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  body: data
  }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })  
});
```

OR
If you're trying to get him to JSON:

```js
fetch("http://example.com/api.php",{
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
     Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    username: this.state.Username,
    password: this.state.Password,
  }),
  }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })  
});
```

Comment: It's alerting `object object`

Comment: @Jason You can try `alert(JSON.stringify(res))`  OR `console.log(res)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending a request of type `application/json`, you should send the data directly as a JSON string:

```js
var data = JSON.stringify(payload);
```